# Ubuntu 14.04 crashing on viewing youtube video in google chrome

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome

I am running the 32-bit version of ubuntu 14.04 and using Version 43.0.2357.81 of Google Chrome (google-chrome-stable) on it. 
Youtube usually works fine with Mozilla firfox, but as I start a youtube video on Chrome,

1. Menu bar, unity bar vanish!
2. Screen blinks and the screen locks (requesting password)
3. Upon unlocking, screen blinks again, then repeat steps 2 and 3 forever till I give up and restart.

I have tried installing Google Chrome through:-

1. www.google.com/chrome
2. google-chrome-stable via Ubuntu Software Center
3. installed an older stable version of chrome and updated it through the terminal.

I have even re-installed ubuntu assuming that there might be some issue with the original installation. Nothing works! Any ideas?

Thanks :)

P.S.: Works fine in mozilla firefox and the youtube unity web app though

Comment: Is switching browsers an option? Or is Google Chrome necessary?

Comment: Well, I use chrome on my company system too,  which runs on windows and does not have firefox.

Comment: Okay, so I tried something else. I removed the stable installation of chrome and changed to "Version 44.0.2403.18 beta". 
It worked fine right after the installation; after a restart to check, the problem persists. 
I am curious now!

Comment: Strange. Perhaps you should file a bug report to Google...

Comment: Is switching to a different browser an option?